# Any way of filtering image with artifacts from a stream?

Tags: opencv, h.264, rtsp, libavcodec, libav

I'm using libav coupled with OpenCV to write to disk some frames coming from a RTSP stream. The entirety of the testing code (based on some in-house code) is the following:

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

using namespace std;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;
using std::this_thread::sleep_until;
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        cerr << "./raw_libav <URI>" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    constexpr int width = 800, height = 600;

    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_VERBOSE);
    shared_ptr<void> defer_network_deinit(nhttp://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_operatorullptr,
                                          bind(avformat_network_deinit));
    auto format_context = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (!format_context) {
        cerr << 0 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    shared_ptr<void> defer_free_context(format_context, avformat_free_context);

    if (avformat_open_input(&format_context, argv[1], nullptr, nullptr) < 0) {
        cerr << 1 << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(format_context, nullptr) < 0) {
        cerr << 2 << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    av_dump_format(format_context, 0, argv[1], false);

    AVCodec *codec;
    auto stream_id = av_find_best_stream(format_context, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1,
                                         -1, &codec, 0);
    if (stream_id < 0) {
        cerr << 3 << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    auto codec_context = format_context->streams[stream_id]->codec;
    if (avcodec_open2(codec_context, codec, nullptr) < 0) {
        cerr << 4 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    shared_ptr<void> defer_free_codec_context(codec_context, avcodec_close);

    auto sws_context =
        sws_getContext(codec_context->width, codec_context->height,
                       codec_context->pix_fmt, width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                       SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!sws_context) {
        cerr << 5 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    shared_ptr<void> defer_free_sws_context(sws_context, sws_freeContext);

    auto frame_in = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame_in) {
        cerr << 6 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    shared_ptr<void> defer_free_frame_in(&frame_in, av_frame_free);

    auto frame_out = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame_out) {
        cerr << 7 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    shared_ptr<void> defer_free_frame_out(&frame_out, av_frame_free);

    auto picture = static_cast<uint8_t *>(av_malloc(
        sizeof(uint8_t) * avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, width, height)));
    if (!picture) {
        cerr << 8 << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    shared_ptr<void> defer_free_picture(picture, av_free);

    if (avpicture_fill(reinterpret_cast<AVPicture *>(frame_out), picture,
                       AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, width, height) < 0) {
        cerr << 9 << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int result;
    string image_dir("capture/");
    result = system(("rm -rf " + image_dir).c_str());
    result = system(("mkdir -p " + image_dir).c_str());

    AVPacket packet;
    for (int frame_count = 1;; ++frame_count) {
        cout << "Frame " << frame_count << endl;
        constexpr int rate = 5;
        auto check_point =
            high_resolution_clock::now() + milliseconds(1000 / rate);
        for (;;) {
            if (av_read_frame(format_context, &packet) < 0) {
                cerr << 10 << endl;http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_operator
                continue;
            }
            shared_ptr<void> defer_av_free_packet(&packet, av_free_packet);

            if (packet.stream_index != stream_id) {
                cerr << 11 << endl;
                continue;
            }

            int ready;
            if (avcodec_decode_video2(codec_context, frame_in, &ready,
                                      &packet) < 0) {
                cerr << 12 << endl;
                continue;
            }
            if (!ready) {
                cerr << 13 << endl;
                continue;
            }

            sws_scale(sws_context, frame_in->data, frame_in->linesize, 0,
                      frame_in->height, frame_out->data, frame_out->linesize);
            break;
        }
        cout << "Writing frame to disk" << endl;

        stringstream image_path;
        image_path << image_dir << '/' << frame_count << ".png";
        auto frame_mat = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3, frame_out->data[0]);
        cv::imwrite(image_path.str(), frame_mat);
        sleep_until(check_point);
    }
}
```

It's my first time trying to deal with a camera stream using libav. Several of the frames contain really bad artifacts, I've tried to check whether there's any correlation between the logging messages and the bad frames but it doesn't seem to have any correspondence.

I'd like to discard the bad frames, is there something wrong with the usage of the API in the testing code that could be generating such frames? Is there a way of knowing a frame is bad from the libav API, not by using some algorithmic approach over the images (which is my last resort)?

### UPDATE

It's known that bad frames are/can-be generated from bad network. Question is whether it's possible to detect and discard them without resorting to image algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

```
codec_context->err_recognition = 0
```

this may misdetect some more or less valid parts as errors and some codecs may return uninitialized/zero data instead of discarding the frame